# Can't get a part of Intermediate Value Theorem proof below

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

Here's the proof itself:

[image]
[image]
**How do they come to this(from the preceding lines of the proof):**

"It cannot be that $w > c$ or else $|w - f(x_i)| \ge w-c\ \forall i \in \mathbb N$ which is absurd."?

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are *forbidden* on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If $f(x_i)<c$ for all $i$, then $$w=\lim_{i\to \infty } f(x_i)\leq c.$$

Indeed, if $w>c$, then there is $i$ s.t. $c<f(x_i)<w$ which is a contradiction with $f(x_i)\leq c$ for all $i$.

- In general, if a sequence is s.t. $x_n< \ell$ for all $n$, then $$\lim_{n\to \infty }x_n\leq \ell.$$
- In your proof, since $f(x_i)\leq c$ for all $i$, if $w>c$, then $$f(x_i) <c\implies -c\leq -f(x_i)\implies 0 <w-c<w-f(x_i) \leq |f(x_i)-w|.$$
  Therefore, $$\lim_{i\to \infty }|f(x_i)-w|\geq w-c>0,$$
  which contradict that $f(x_i)\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow} w$.

Comment: Now i see. You've re-phrased the claim questioned as if $w > c$ then there is $i$ s.t. $c < f(x_i)<w$ which is a contradiction with $f(x_i) \le c \forall i$ and right that moment i realized what I'd missed :)